# PHP encryption not working on server

Tags: php, linux, encryption, cryptography, php-openssl

I'm trying to store encrypted cookies in a PHP app and have implemented 2 different encryption libraries in attempts to get this to work.

Both implementations, when deployed to the server, are generating fatal exceptions when calling my encryption function. On my local dev env, however, both encryption implementations are working successfully.

My open_ssl implementation code (works on localhost, does not work on remote server):

```php
set_encrypted_cookie("foo","my_cookie_name");

function set_encrypted_cookie($msg,$name){
    $key = '0123456qwerty'; // Key is stored externally but defined locally for debugging

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    $encryptedStr = openssl_encrypt($msg, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);

    setcookie($name,$encryptedStr,0,'/');
}
```

Any thoughts on why the server might be not allowing the openssl_encrypt() func to execute?

Comment: can you print the full Exception/Error Message ?

Comment: @halayemanis Found this in the logs - PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_iv_size() - turns out that my remote server didn't have the php56-mcrypt dependency installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`openssl_encrypt()` returns raw binary, you should `base64_encode()` before storing in a cookie.

Before you do that, a couple of things you can do to improve your cryptography protocol:

1. Use `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM`, not `MCRYPT_RAND`.
2. Store your IV with your ciphertext (before `base64_encode()`ing it), so you can use the same IV when decrypting.
3. [Encrypt then MAC](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).

The last link has two functions, `setLessUnsafeCookie()` and `getLessUnsafeCookie()`, that you can use as a drop-in on PHP 5.6.x.

There are still two more things to do to make it safe to use:

1. Use HKDF to split the key into an encryption key and a decryption key.
2. Use PKCS7 padding on the plaintext.

(If you want to go for maximum security, you can [use libsodium](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-safely-implement-cryptography-in-any-application) instead of openssl.) Also, [don't use mcrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).